# Using Python & Selenium Package to create a script that switches the Chrome Dark Mode on off. How to select element in chrome://?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, mode

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("chrome://flags/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    firsts = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "#enable-force-dark")))
    firsts.click()

    seconds = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.NAME, "enable-force-dark_name"))
    seconds.click()
```

I'm trying to use selenium to go to chrome://flags/ and enable / disable the force dark mode theme. I have tried to use x-path, class etc to reach this button but for some reason i cant access it. would it be better for me to try to use a different method of selecting this drop down list? thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is not proper handling of browser settings in automation. you should control your browser via capabilities.

`capabilities.chromeOptions.args = ['--force-dark-mode']`

// Forces dark mode in UI for platforms that support it.