# Python Selenium, how do I open a page in dark mode?

Tags: python, selenium

im trying to open [this page](https://www.reddit.com/) in dark mode, using selenium and python. however anything i try doesnt seem to work. this is the code i believe should work:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument('--force-dark-mode')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

link = "https://www.reddit.com"

driver.get(link)
```

a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745896/using-python-selenium-package-to-create-a-script-that-switches-the-chrome-dark) but doesnt work.

also i have looked at the [command switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), and it doesnt work for me.

edit:
[this is what im looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK4EV.png), which can be achieved by enabling [this chrome flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p0OG.png). my goal is to launch the webpage with that flag enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that same problem with Reddit before, but I did it manually, found the dropdown, then settings and then turned on dark mode.

```
driver.get(url)
btn = driver.find_element(By.ID,'USER_DROPDOWN_ID')
btn.click()
settings = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"icon-settings")
settings.click()
dark = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Dark Mode']")
dark.click()
btn.click()
```

Comment: thanks alot! this what i wanted. wish there was a better way than automatically clicking buttons each time but this will do!

Answer (score 0):

I do see it is working, the driver browser is opened in the dark mode.
This is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--force-dark-mode')

s = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=s)

url = 'https://www.reddit.com'

driver.get(url)
```

And this is the screenshot of the opened browser
[image]

Comment: ive edited my post to be slightly more clear in what im looking for

Comment: I see. I don't know how to make the entire page dark. I applied the option you mentioned and got the result as you can see in my answer. In case you finally find a way to make the entire page dark - please let me know, it's interesting